# AFNetworking.h file not found

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods

I am using `pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.0'`.

But every time I am getting this error:

[image]

Recently I updated my mac gems. After updating gems I am getting this error.

Can you please any one help?

Comment: Already I tried it but no luck.

Comment: does 'AFNetworking.h' exist inside Pods directory?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

instead of

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

And, of course, do not forget to check the header paths inside your project properties and check if cocoapods correctly installed 'AFNetworking' project. Try to find AFNetworking.h file inside 'pods' directory.

**EDIT**
Type, what is writen inside 'header search path'
1.
[image]
2. What is placed inside /path/to/app/Pods/Headers/Public/ ?

Comment: I replaced  #import "AFNetworking.h" insted of #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h> but no luck.I am new for this, Can you please tell me how to check project properties

Comment: @Baadshah , at first , is this the only cocoapods project you use?

Comment: Yes i am using cocoapods.

Comment: Don't forget to choose `All` label on the header section. See this answer for a screenshot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48140171/1817042

Answer (score 3):

If you have updated your gems, check version of cocoapods if is version 1.0.0, probably you need to change your Podfile.

ex:

```
platform :ios, 'IOS_VERSION_HERE'
target 'YOUR_TARGET_HERE' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.0'
    pod ...
    pod ..
end
```

After that in terminal go to you project folder where is the Podfile located and write command:

`pod update`

After that if you see some warnings try to fix them. The warnings will guide you what to do if is necessary. 
Then try to clean your project and Build it again.

**IMPORTANT!!!**

When you use Pod's you **must** open ***YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace*** instead of ***YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj***

Hope this help.

Comment: I am using 1.0.0 version of cocoapod.i updated the pod.                                       use_frameworks!

platform :ios, '8.0'
target "TARGET" do
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
pod 'HockeySDK'
pod 'FPPicker', '~> 5.1.2'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
end    But no luck

Comment: What you are open YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace or YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj ? I mean do you see your Pods project  in your work space? After `pod update` do you receive any warnings ?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Next steps always help me to fix the issue:

1. Select `Pods` file in your project.
2. Open the `Build settings` for `Pods` project
3. Set `Build Active Architecture Only` to false. Build and Run the project again.

Comment: This worked for me at the end of 2022, had to resurrect a really old project.

Answer (score 2):

After updating pod's to (pod 'AFNetworking', '3.0') I was facing same issue.

Replacing

> ## #import "AFNetworking.h"

With

> ## @import AFNetworking;

solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I couldn't build and got the error message `'AFCompatibilityMacros.h' file not found`

Simply running `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` fixed it. I found the solution in [this discussion](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4202).

Comment: well how ever this is work for me, Thanks!