# Header Search Path,Library path and Linking path section is missing in Xcode 9.2

Tags: xcode, swift4

Like to add third-party library path in the setting panel of my project but the problem is there is no Header Search Path, Library path, and Linking path section.Missing the Header search paths section

I am using Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4
[image]

[image: Search Path Section is missing]

Comment: you are taking about bridging header ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Click on **All** and **Combined** button. You see the header search Path.

[image]

Comment: I have two options below 'Header Search Paths' Debug and Release, where do I need to change? I am using High Seirra and XCode 9.3.1. Where do I put my changes?