# AFNetworking.h file not found in latest xcode

Tags: ios, afnetworking

AFNetworking.h file not found issue occurred when build preparing in latest xCode.

Comment: Hi can you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433129/afnetworking-h-file-not-found

Comment: Sorry issue still occurred.